# compare Object attribute value inside list

Tags: java, collections

```
Class Order
{
  String  name;
  Order(String n)
   { name = n; }

 //setter and getters of name
}

Order a = new Order("same");
Order b = new Order("same");
Order c = new Order("diff");

List<Order> nameList// a,b,c
```

I want to

```
seperate list of Orders 
     List<Order> dupList// a,b
     List<Order> nondupList// c
```

Now I want to check whether same name is  available in multiple orders of "nameList".

I achieved that using index of List and compare with other than that index List Orders.

But is there any other better way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you want to do when the same name is found?

Comment: Thanks for reply.... I want to take them as separate list

Comment: So, you want to have all of them in separate, or just the duplicates? Can you post an expected output for some given input?

Comment: just I updated the question pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one other way could be - Override hashCode method and equals method. Generate hasCode on calculation of string name.

```
public class Order {
    String name;

    public Order(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    // setter and getters of name
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = 0;
        int len = name.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            h = 31 * h + name.charAt(i);
        return h;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        else if(this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

...

```
List<Order> nameList = ...;// a,b,c
Set<Order> nonDuplicate= new HashSet<Order>(nameList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure java, add the elements to the a List, and `sort` it with the appropriate comparator. Then iterate over the list, keeping track of the previous element, doing a control break; in other words, if the element is the same as the previous both are a duplicate. If they are not (or it is the first), they are a candidate and you need to wait for the next check to find a duplicate.

If you don't want to sort, you can add the elements to a Set as they appear; if before adding an element it is already in the set, you can add it to the duplicate set. You can do the check on both sets removing as you go, or remove from the complete set the duplicates at the end. You can use any collection, but Set is more efficient since it has a fast contains method.

If you can use libraries, you can just use Guava and add everything to a multiset (http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html ) Then iterate over the multiset and you have the count per element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Map>, get list for given name, if null, create it and put it in, add current order in that list.